# Can I get a hold of Button Location Data in my Android Application

Tags: android, button, drawing

In my application, I'm (still) trying to manipulate my Button Views to look the way I want.  I'd like to attempt an experiment where I'll draw an Android Rect or RectF in the same location as the (transparent) button to highlight it's appearance.

However, I can't figure out how to get my mitts on that information.  The buttons in question are defined in XML, in a Linear Layout, but something inside my Android has to know their sizes and locations.  Right?

Any suggestions?
Thanks, R.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  What can you not do with custom drawables set as the button backgroun?

Comment: The buttons in question are transparent (there's active content going on behind them).  I want to draw a frame around the button's edge and I have been completely unsuccessful and finding a way to do this by addressing the button directly.  I thought I would look into drawing a Rect on the screen in the same location as the button.  However, if you can suggest an alternative, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Okay, but that would first require MAKING (or "obtaining") the custom drawable, wouldn't it??  Any suggestions for how I might do that?

Comment: I don't know if carrying on this conversation in the comments section is exactly the right way to do things, but your drawable seems to be working quite well.  Thanks.

Comment: Oops.  Hit Return prematurely...  Can you suggest how I might round the corners of the buttons I'm now drawing?? I found a question on S.O. where the poster had a subsection called "corners" inside his XML shape description, and his pictures looked right, but it's not working for me.

Comment: I removed my comments and posted everything in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set a background of the button to a custom xml drawable with the drawable containing only stroke element around the edge.

You will need to create this custom drawable: it would be just a few lines of XML.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**Edit:** updated to include rounded corners.

Comment: Do you know (or know where I can find) an XML file that approximately describes the exact default button that shows up in an Android application if you don't change a single detail (which I know is a nine-patch, but it would seem like useful information)?

Comment: @Rich I don't know about the XML itself, but the background images can be referenced with `android.R.xxx` values.  Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a combination of my poking around and Aleks' suggestion to use a custom drawable.  Ultimately, my custom drawable needed more than three lines, but it's still not very big:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape>

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@android:color/black"
                android:endColor="@android:color/black" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#cccccc" />

            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />

            <padding
                android:left="4dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:bottom="2dp" />

        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

I needed to add all of the other detail to get the custom button to work the way I wanted -- and I'm probably not done, but if anybody is interested, this works pretty well...